# Jenkins setup to run selenium ide script using selenium rc

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am not able to run selenium ide scripts through jenkins. It hangs at checking resource aliases and does not open any browser.

I have tried the following things for setup:

I have configured selenium server as below:

Jenkins Dashboard -> configure -> Selenium Remote Control -> htmlSuite Runner -> C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar

I have configured the job as below:

Job -> Job Name -> Configure -> Build -> SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run-> browser: *firefox
startURL: https://google.com/
suiteFile: C:\Scripts\Suite.html
resultFile: C:\Scripts\results.html`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't do this.. don't use Selenium IDE scripts if you are going to have a build system integrated.  Take the time to learn a language of your choice, and do it that way. I'd recommend Java as Jenkins is built on java and supports it right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

following @glomad's guidance I needed to do something similar to this and I solved it as follows, I hope it helps others:

1. I created a selenium grid on a remote server, as per the documentation

Download [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file and run:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

```
docker compose up -d
```

[image]

2. right after I installed [selenium ide](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) in chrome, and collected the tests.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd

3. Create and export the test to jUnit. When importing, inform the Remote URL of the selenium Grid

[image]

[image]

4. I created a new project (spring boot) and imported the class
   generated in selenium ide.

added dependency in your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5. I made some corrections in the imports
6. In jenkins I configured the pipeline to download the project and
   perform the configured tests.

```bash
...
stage('Run Tests') {
     steps {
        sh 'mvn test'
     }
 }
```

7. Everything went as expected.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.